# How to get attribute value using node value in PHP DOM XPath

Tags: php, xpath

I have XML structure like below. XML is very large I am just showing related part.

```
<data>
    <book>
        <name xml:lang='Eng'>someValue</name>
    </book>
</data>
```

I have to find out attribute value using node value.
I have values of all book names in array. So I have value **someValue** using it I have to find out value of attribute **xml:lang**. Expected output is **Eng** in this case. I searched for answer but all are for reverse case that is get node value using attribute value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following XPath

```
//data/book/name[text()='someValue']/@xml:lang"
```

The [`xml:` namespace](https://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace) is  included in the XML spec and so doesn't need to be defined separately.